# Eclipse won't run - JVM Terminated, Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, eclipse, jdk

Installed eclipse neon using installer from eclipse website.
I have java 8 jdk from oracle.
When trying to run eclipse i get the following:

```
JVM terminated. Exit code=13
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone    /latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-jar /home/adiel/eclipse/cpp-neon/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
-os linux
-ws gtk
-arch x86_64
-showsplash
-launcher /home/adiel/eclipse/cpp-neon/eclipse/eclipse
-name Eclipse
--launcher.library /home/adiel/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444    /eclipse_1617.so
-startup /home/adiel/eclipse/cpp-neon/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
--launcher.appendVmargs
-exitdata 490011
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
-vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
-jar /home/adiel/eclipse/cpp-neon/eclipse//plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
```

Can someone please help

**Update:**
My eclipse.ini file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
--launcher.library
/home/adiel/.p2/pool/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
-Declipse.p2.max.threads=10
-Doomph.update.url=http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
-Doomph.redirection.index.redirection=index:/->http://git.eclipse.org/c/oomph/org.eclipse.oomph.git/plain/setups/
```

`java -version` shows:

```
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)
```

while `which java` shows:

```
/usr/bin/java
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the contents of  `/etc/eclipse.ini`?

Comment: Looks like `/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/java` must be a 32 bit Java - it must be 64 bit to match Eclipse (or use a 32 bit Eclipse).

Comment: @Ron - posted. greg-449 , See update. installed java is 64 bit

Comment: Whats the output if you try to open Eclipse from terminal: `eclipse` ?